# Angular2 - is it possible to get component class name using selector name

Tags: angular, typescript, annotations, angular2-components, angular2-decorators

Is it possible to get component class name or component reference using selector name in Angular 2?

```
@Component({
  selector: 'selector-1',
  template: '<h1>Hello</h1>',
})
export class Component1 {}

@Component({
      selector: 'selector-2',
      template: '<h1>Hello</h1>',
    })
    export class Component2 {}
```

In component 2 is it possible to get the component1 class name using selector "selector-1"?

**Example:**

```
getComponentName(selectorName) {
 // return component name
}

getComponentName('selector-1');
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible without additional work only if you do not call `enableProdMode`:

```
var node = document.querySelector('selector-1');
var debugNode = window.ng.probe(node);
var name = debugNode.componentInstance.constructor.name;
```

Otherwise you will have to maintain component map yourself.